# Split Accordion panels into multiple files in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, accordion, code-separation

I have five panels with some logic in every of them.

How could I split styles, code and layout for every panel to several files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of your question is correct, you just have to create as many customs components inheriting `s:NavigatorContent` as panels.
Each one can have is own style and behaviour.

Headers must be styled at runtime since they share the same class `<mx:Accordion headerRenderer="MyHeaderClass"/>`.

However, you could customize everything you want by using the `WindowShade` component of the `FlexLib`, including different HeaderRenderers.

Nimaen